# Matlab Function fails due to : 'Error using Eval', works fine when used in Command Window

Tags: matlab, plot

When plotting data from a .mat file, if I enter the lines from a script one-by-one, it works fine... but when I try running the script, it fails.

```
function Test (filename)  

   varname = load (filename)  %or load filename                                                     
   matObj = matfile(filename);
   varlist = who (matObj);   %or varlist = fieldnames (varname)  
   field1 = eval ( varlist {1} )
   field2 = eval ( varlist {2} )
   x1 = field1.x_values.start_value:field1.x_values.increment:field1.x_values.increment*field1.x_values.number_of_values;
   x2 = field2.x_values.start_value:field2.x_values.increment:field2.x_values.increment*field2.x_values.number_of_values;
   figure
   hold all

   %Support for yyaxis left/right not avaiable, so use plotyy
   plotyy (x1, field1.y_values.values, x2, field2.y_values.values)

end
```

When I invoke the script (Test ('1.mat')), Matlab shows an error on the field1 = line :

```
  Error using eval
  Undefined function or variable 'Signal'.
```

The 'Signal' is one of the data set names in the 1.mat file.

Interestingly, when I run each line by itself in the same order from the command window, I don't get any error and the plot displays.   I verified that the current path has the script and the 1.mat file, but I can't figure out why it complains about the eval when run from the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because your `matObj` is a `*.mat` file which contains the variable named `Signal`. You never load the file in your function (using `load`) but instead you assign a [`matfile` object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) to `matObj`. To read a variable from this **do not use `eval` (*ever*)**, rather you just want to use [dynamic fields referencing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) into the `matfile` object.

```
field1 = matObj.(varlist{1});
field2 = matObj.(varlist{2});
```

In general though, you should probably *know* the name of the variables you're trying to load from the file rather than simply using the first two variables you find  with `who`. If that's the case, just use them directly.

```
field1 = matObj.Signal;
```

The reason that your code likely worked in the command window is because at some point you probably loaded the .mat file into the command window workspace using `load` which would have loaded all it's contents (including `Signal`) into the workspace.

```
load('filename.mat')
```

Also as a bit of a nit-pick. You don't have a script you have a *function* (you have a `function` definition at the top). This has huge ramifications for diagnosing your problem. You *cannot* test a *function* by copy/pasting stuff into the command window due to the different scope of a function.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!   Functions vs scripts are a bit confusing..  to create a standalone exe, I always set the top level .m file to a file containg a function.    Then from the Window's command line, I can execute the .exe and pass it any arguments the function needs.    Can the same thing be accomplished using a script as the top level .m file?   How would arguments be passed in?